# Tkinter button linked to function with argument gives TypeError

Tags: python, string, lambda, typeerror

I'm trying to run a function called password() with argument "t" on pressing a button in Tkinter.

Problem is that this gives me a TypeError even though the code seems alright.

```py
self.Button5.configure(command=lambda t='restart': password(t))
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

(here is a link to whole code if necessary, error is on line 372: https://codeshare.io/G8VW6A)

Comment: That error message suggests the object 'password' is a string

Comment: what do you mean? password is function (defined on line 154)

Comment: @koumakpet does `self.Button5.configure(command=lambda: password('restart'))` work?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis no, same problem

Comment: @DeepSpace Actually it does not. Try `f = lambda x, t=' bar': x+t` with `f('foo')`.

Comment: I know where was the problem @strava aleardy answered it, but thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line 103 of your code you create global variable 'password', which has the same name as your function. Just change the variable names so they don't clash.